# How to select all types of child element inside an SVG using d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

To select all type of "rect" within an svg element we write this

```
svg.selectAll('rect')
```

But, here if i want to select everything within a SVG element including `rect` and `circle` and `images` etc and perform some common operation on all of them, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

d3 uses css selectors so you want use an [* (universal selector)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors):

```
svg.selectAll('*')
```

Comment: Ohh right..Thank you go-oleg for your answer. That was so obvious and did not come to my mind.. :P